# Type new line in Cypress test

Tags: javascript, cypress, textarea

Can someone, assist in apparently, simple and silly issue, which I am struggling to fix.
Namely, have a simple JSON

```
{
"collapsible": true
}
```

to type in textarea for **Cypress** test.
Tried different solutions such are:

```
'{{} ' + '\n' + '"collapsible": true' + '\n' + ' {}}'
'{{} {enter} "collapsible": true {enter} {}}'
'{{}' + {enter} + ' "collapsible": true' + {enter} + '{}}'
...
```

But, without any success. Always get:

```
{ "collapsible": true }
```

Does anyone has the solution - how to simulate new line?
Thank you in advance

Update:
Result is:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Alapan Das, which provide me the idea.
Solution is as follows:

```
cy.get('selector')
.type('{')
.type('{shift}{enter}')
.type(`"collapsible": true`)
.type('{shift}{enter}')
.type('}')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in three steps:

```js
cy.get('selector')
  .type('{')
  .type('{rightArrow}{enter}')
  .type(`"collapsible": true`)
  .click()
  .type('{rightArrow}{enter}')
  .type('}')
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly, same result.

Added scrrenshots how it looks

Comment: @ Alapan Das
Nope, same result for the update, too.
Also found that arrow is not working: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/8561